# Is it possible to test for support for ::marker content using @supports?

Tags: css, webkit

I wanted to make a nested ordered list with a specific numbering system, like so:

https://www.stairball.club/stairball-rules/

Here's the relevant CSS I'm using:

```css
/* Numbering for nested rule lists */
.rule-list ol {
    counter-reset: rules;
}
.rule-list li {
    counter-increment: rules;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.rule-list li li {
    font-weight: initial;
}

.rule-list li::marker {
    content: counters(rules, '.') '. ';
    font-weight: bold;
}
/* Don't apply to Webkit which doesn't support ::marker content */
@supports (-webkit-hyphens: auto) {
    .rule-list li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .rule-list li::before {
        content: counters(rules, '.') '. ';
        color: #E77B95;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: -2em;
    }
}
```

I based my code on this lovely article, [Styling Ordered Lists with CSS Counters](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/styling-ordered-lists-with-css-counters/).

Replacing the li marker with the numbering system I want to use was straightforward in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari refuses to do the replacement: https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/984

[Safari/WebKit supports the ::marker pseudo-element](https://caniuse.com/?search=marker), but not the content property. So I need to fall back to using the ::before pseudoelement, but this is apparently [bad for accessibility](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204163#c9), and it also looks bad because I'm not able to get the indentation right. The numbers do not appear where a marker would appear, they appear in the text itself. I'm currently giving them a negative margin to move the numbers to the left, but this isn't adequate beyond the first level of nesting.

Right now I am testing whether the browser is WebKit with [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports), by checking whether the browser supports -webkit-hyphens, which I know only WebKit supports. This is not ideal, however, because if WebKit fixes support for the content property in the future, new WebKit browers won't automatically start using my preferred code. I won't be able to differentiate between old broken WebKit and new fixed WebKit. Also, if there are other stupid browsers like WebKit, I won't be able to detect their brokenness.

Is there any way to test for support for the content property under a selector using the ::marker pseudo-element?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, the approach is to provide the marker and the fallback for older browsers it ... so what if it aint so pretty.